# C# Entity Framework database first missing key violation EntitySet '' is based on type '' that has no keys defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I'm stumped with this. I'm using Entity Framework (EF 6.1.3) and generated a database-first model (this is the weird part because most of the googling I've done has results for code first).

When I'm trying to query the database, I get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:TCCIntegration.DataAccess.Ozone.Context.CORP_MASTER: : EntityType 'CORP_MASTER' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType" "Define the key for this EntityType. CorpMaster: EntityType: EntitySet 'CorpMaster' is based on type 'CORP_MASTER' that has no keys defined.

But I can see in the actual SQL database that there is a primary key defined and also in the `.EDMX`, I can see that the primary key is included in the model.

Plus the problem with it being database-first, I can't add any data annotations to the models because they are automatically generated. Is there something obvious I am missing? (I have tried removing the tables from the `.EDMX` and re-adding them and also refreshing the `.EDMX`)

Here's the SQL DDL (Thanks STLDeveloper)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CORP_MASTER](
[CORP_MASTER__ID] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[CORP_MAST_ACQUIRED] [varchar](2) NULL,
[CORP_MAST_YEAR_START] [int] NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_CORP_MASTER] PRIMARY KEY 
CLUSTERED 
(
[CORP_MASTER__ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

EDIT
[CodeName47] The EDMX does show that they should be keys

[image: Table Mapping Design and Properties]

EDIT

I've created an empty console app and tried this again with the same result. 
I have a class that inherits from DbContext

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class OzoneLiveLite : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CORP_MASTER> CorpMaster { get; set; }      
    }
}
```

A provider class

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class OzoneLiveLiteProvider 
    {
        private readonly OzoneLiveLite _ozoContext;
        public OzoneLiveLiteProvider() : this(new OzoneLiveLite())
       {
       }

       public OzoneLiveLiteProvider(OzoneLiveLite ozoneLiveLiteProvider)
        {
            _ozoContext = ozoneLiveLiteProvider;
        }

        public void GetProjectFinancials()
        {
            var corpMaster = _ozoContext.CorpMaster;
            var ozoneFinancials = from corpMast in corpMaster select corpMast.CORP_MASTER__ID;
       }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _ozoContext?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the Main class

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            var ozoneProvider = new OzoneLiveLiteProvider();
            ozoneProvider.GetProjectFinancials();
            Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
}
```

Is there possibly something wrong in the way I'm implementing the context?

Comment: Please provide the SQL DDL for the `CORP_MASTER` table, including the definition of the primary key.

Comment: Apologies - SQL Data Definition Language - the `CREATE TABLE` statement that was used to create the `CORP_MASTER` table.

Comment: You should add that DDL for the `CORP_MASTER` table to your question, rather than posting it in a comment.

Comment: It might also be good to know what version of EF you're working with.

Comment: Edited and added version(6.1.3) Thanks man i appreciate the assistance with formulating the question.

Comment: since your id is not int and also not the expected name 'Id' you may need to decorate with attributes key

Comment: I had thought that but because it's database first I can't add an attribute to the model ?

Comment: have you tried the haskey in the model to specify?

Comment: Please go to the designer and select the column and click properties. There you can set the EntityKey property to make it primary key

Comment: Not sure where i would apply the haskey method, as i understand it, normally it would go in the context overriding the OnModelCreating method but because this is database first that method shoudn't be used should it? (i did actually end up trying that but no change)

    modelBuilder.Entity<CORP_MASTER>().HasKey(c => c.CORP_MASTER__ID);

Comment: please try to reproduce this in a smaller project with just a console app and a edmx. Post this in github. lets see what is the problem. In my code sample it works as it should.

Comment: That's a really good idea, i'll give that a go, thanks

Answer (score 1):

And that's exactly what it came down to, a bit of ignorance and a whole lot of stupid on my part. On my context class I was inheriting from DbContext() instead of the auto generated partial entities class.

so my context looked like

```
 public class OzoneLiveLite : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CORP_MASTER> CorpMaster { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_FINYEAR> JcsFinyear { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_JOB> JcsJob { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_JOB__JCS_JOB_SUBJOB> JcsJobJcsJobSubjob { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_FINYEAR__JCFY_PERIOD> JcsFinyearJcfyPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of

```
 public class OzoneLiveLite : Ozone_Live_LiteEntities
{
    public DbSet<CORP_MASTER> CorpMaster { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_FINYEAR> JcsFinyear { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_JOB> JcsJob { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_JOB__JCS_JOB_SUBJOB> JcsJobJcsJobSubjob { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JCS_FINYEAR__JCFY_PERIOD> JcsFinyearJcfyPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

To be honest I'm still not sure why it allowed me to build and only failed at runtime but it looks like my issue is solved for the moment.

Thank you all for the assist

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

If you don't have standard primary key names and non integer primary keys the ef may not identify your primary keys.

**You can make the column as primary key by the below steps**

1. Go to the designer and select the column
2. click properties.
3. Set the EntityKey property to true

**Property section of the column**

[image]